# how to play hls_stream from json api in ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am trying to play a  hls_stream from json api in ionic one

There are not errors at all

what i have tried/trying and cant get to work:

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in lives" ng-show="item.id == liveid">
    <video poster="{{item.image}}" preload="auto" autoplay class="theplayios" height="100%" width="100%" webkit-playsinline controls>
      <source src="{{item.url}}" dynamic-url dynamic-url-src="{{item.url}}">
    </video>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var vid = document.createElement('video');
      document.getElementById('typ').innerHTML = vid.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl');
    </script>
  </div>
```

The api http://tvstartup.biz/mng-channel/vpanel/api/livestreams.php?user=hoy&pass=076fdf74936ebae00e7949a80f61f985

JS:

```
        $scope.liveid = $stateParams.playId;

        $http.get('http://tvstartup.biz/mng-channel/vpanel/api/livestreams.php?user=' + $scope.apiusername + '&pass=' + $scope.apipassword).success(function(data) {
            $scope.lives = data.allstreams;
        });
```

[image]

Comment: What version of Angular?

Comment: @Phil it's AngularJS

Comment: Yeah, no kidding. **What version?**

Comment: how do i get the versjion @Phil

Comment: can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing a bit of network traffic analysis. Take a look at the response from the API.

the $http service has changed a bit, but if you are not getting errors, then your version is probably compatible with the .done syntax.

If that data.allStreams value is being hydrated, then you may have to step into the vid.canPlayType() method and see where it is failing (silently it appears).

Maybe there is a way to get more verbose debug info - try adjusting your debug console in chrome to emit verbose levels.